# Can you turn off the (the lighting) of the Touch Bar on the new MacBook Pros?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

So I don't have a the new MacBook Pro here, but can you actually turn the TouchBar off, like you can turn off the backlit keyboard, when you're watching movie in example?

Searching on Apple.com to do some research didn't find any information about this function.

Can a tool or setting or script turn off the touch bar illumination on demand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can turn off the Touch Bar with this open source utility: Touch Bar Disabler.

(The original repo of Touch Bar Disabler: https://github.com/HiKay/TouchBarDisabler was removed. An archive of the  repo can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170609220926/https://github.com/HiKay/TouchBarDisabler)

Touch Bar Disabler disables the Touch Bar display, while mapping brightness controls onto <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, volume controls onto <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

[image: Touch Bar Disabler's screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

You can't actually turn it off manually but it will automatically after 75 seconds of inactivity (Trackpad or Keyboard). It could be nice to turn it off manually or at least change the duration. I hope it will be implemented in the future.

Comment: Considering you have just recently joined and therefore haven't yet gain any appreciable reputation, maybe if you add an authoritative reference to your answer it might get some up-votes. As it stands now, I'm not inclined to up-vote it. You might what to read [How do I write a good answer?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, there is no official documentation from Apple stating it is possible. So how is he supposed to link to something that does not exist?

Comment: @DisplayName I think he is asking for a source about the 45 seconds

Comment: @user3439894 Well, you might as well test it for yourself by grabbing a timer and validating the claim... Given the following two facts:

1. Apple has no official documentation on this
2. End-user cannot change the duration

OP shouldn't have to cite his sources here regardless of the level of specificity this post has. Although things may have changed since 3 years ago

Answer (score 7):

A new alternative is "Hide My Bar". Hotkey can be changed, also if the Touch Bar is hidden, you can change Brightness, Keyboard Brightness and Volume from the menu bar (like w

https://hidemybar.clemstation.com/

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 3):

Touch Bar will turn off after 60 seconds of inactivity.
It's impossible to turn it off manually ATM.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said, in more detail

Comment: It's OK to have a wrong answer - especially when a clear comment can explain how precisely how it's wrong. It might get down votes, but it's OK to have wrong answers. I'm curious why one answer says it turns off at 75 seconds and this says 60 seconds. Might be some good information in both of these answers in addition to [the answer with code that can turn it off on demand](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281570/5472).

Comment: This is just not true. It stays on during no activity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description of how to hide the touch bar with BetterTouch tool ([link](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-disable-or-hide-your-macbooks-touch-bar-1843571363#:%7E:text=How%20to%20blank%20out%20your%20Touch%20Bar)).

My configurations are:

1. Settings > Keyboard
   [image: Settings > Keyboard]
2. Better Touch tool > TouchBar. An empty action and its settings [image] Action settings [image: Action settings]

And now my TouchBar does not show anything until I press `Control` key.

Answer (score 2):

setting **"touch bar shows"** in **keyboard settings** to **"quick actions"** and turning off **"show control strip"** checkbox worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Apple has updated it over a software update. When you click in System Preferences -> Keyboard and then click the keyboard backlight box on and reduce the time, Touch Bar will be affected too. Touch Bar will fade away even if your backlight has set to zero brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problems that most of you described here. The DIY solution I ended up using was setting the Touch Bar keys to a minimum:

[image]

**How to set up the Touch Bar to a minimum?**

Go to Settings -> Keyboard and choose "Touch Bar shows: Expanded Control Strip".
Then click on "Customize Control Strip" button below and add "Space" on each side while removing the other keys.

The advantage of this solution is that I would barely hit the keys by accident.
The downside of it was I couldn't enjoy the cool features from the Touch Bar that come with some app.

I made an app to solve that problem that you can find through my profile but I don't want to promote it here .

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should check https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion, and maybe edit your answer a bit.

Comment: @CodeBrauer thanks for putting me back on the right track :) appreciate it!