# Touch Bar flashing bright white light when Mac is idle

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro with a Touch Bar. The Touch Bar has been flashing bright white light when I don't touch my keyboard or trackpad for a certain amount of time. I also have noticed that the Touch Bar stops flashing when I shine a bright light into the ambient light sensor by the camera. Does anyone know any fixes for this?

Comment: There are various existing questions for how to disable the Touch Bar, such as https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/263418/37797, so I’ve edited the title of this question to focus on the issue you’re having with it.

Comment: From googling around it looks like this is a somewhat known issue with TouchBar Macs and will need a trip to the Apple Store for repair. Potentially a battery issue, so you probably want it looked at.

Answer (score 1):

On my 2019 (Intel) MBP I had the same issue, it started with occasional flashes of the very right square and got worse up to the point of erratic bright flashing of the entire right half of the Touch Bar.

**Resetting the SMC** by shutting down the MBP and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd> and the power button for ~10 seconds did the trick.

The Touch Bar stopped flashing and has behaved as expected ever since.

Here is the official (more detailed) description [Reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

Comment: This did not stop mine 2018 Macbook Pro

Answer (score 1):

I have a 13 inch M1 MacBook Pro (2020). I've been having this problem intermittently. It seems to happen most often after waking from sleep. I find that plugging it into power and then unplugging improves it.

Note that for Mac silicon, the official way to reset the SMC is... to simply restart the computer.

Comment: How does this answer the question? If you have a new question, click [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), provide a link to this thread if it helps to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mid 2020 Intel MacBook Pro, I found a temporary work around - switching between apps using `Cmd-Tab` until the touch bar stops flashing.